# SEOmatic and Global Variables

Tags: variable, globals, plugin-seomatic

We have a Craft site with nearly 800 entries. For SEO purposes we need to change the page title and page (SEO) description for each entry, a laborious task to say the least.

Is there a way to have, say, a PageTitle variable which we apply to all entries with SEOmatic, and if we need to change the structure of the title, we just have to change the PageTitle variable once. This variable itself would have variables within it, e.g:

> Beautiful {villaBedrooms} bedroom villa in {villaLocation.last.title}, Bali. From just ${villaPrice}. {villaHook}

Comment: Is this SEOmatic for Craft 3.x, or Craft 2.x?

Comment: Sorry, this is Craft 2.7 and SEOmatic 1.1.56

Kind regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Craft 2.x, what I'd suggest is just doing this via Twig. This is discussed here: https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/10.-Dynamic-Twig-SEO-Meta